# Cleaning Anaconda to start over

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

I have been experiencing a lot of troubles lately with Anaconda and my environments.
So, I would like to a full clean and start over from scratch.

I wanted to know **if deleting environments and uninstalling everything** as suggested in the official Anaconda Web site also **deletes the notebooks/py-scripts or any other file in the same folders**

Also, if you have any recommendation on the best way to achieve this, it would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by _same folders_ ? The environment folder?

Comment: Yes, I've already cleaned everything and starting from 0. I believe that that question did not make a lot of sense now, but I am not really familiar with this things yet.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps**

*1. save your ipynb files in one folder*

*2. delete anaconda from control panel*

*3. reinstall it*

*4. download libraries which are required*

Thanks

Comment: So you're implying that yes, the files should be backup somewhere else? @Zesty Dragon

Comment: if it's important to you then definitely you should backup them

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to keep backup of your notebooks but you can also use the following command.

```
conda clean {options}
```

Please refer this: [Where does conda clean remove packages from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51960539/where-does-conda-clean-remove-packages-from)